# Where's the error in my MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I get the following error when I run this MySQL query. Where's my problem?

> `#1064` - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 19`

```
select tran_date, tran_id,  
    sum(case account_id when 'M0003' then (cr_amt) else 0 end) as cr_sm,  
    sum(case account_id when 'M0003' then (dr_amt) else 0 end) as dr_sm,  
    sum(case account_id when 'M0003' then (balance) else 0 end) as bal_sm,  
    sum(case account_id when 'MD001' then (cr_amt) else 0 end) as cr_cdnw,  
    sum(case account_id when 'MD001' then (dr_amt) else 0 end) as dr_cdnw,  
    sum(case account_id when 'MD001' then (balance) else 0 end) as bal_cdnw,  
    sum(case account_id when 'MD002' then (cr_amt) else 0 end) as cr_cdw,  
    sum(case account_id when 'MD002' then (dr_amt) else 0 end) as dr_cdw,  
    sum(case account_id when 'MD002' then (balance) else 0 end) as bal_cdw,  
    sum(case account_id when 'ML001' then (cr_amt) else 0 end) as cr_loan_ord,  
    sum(case account_id when 'ML001' then (dr_amt) else 0 end) as dr_loan_ord,  
    sum(case account_id when 'ML001' then (balance) else 0 end) as bal_loan_ord,  
    sum(case account_id when 'ML002' then (cr_amt) else 0 end) as cr_loan_emg,  
    sum(case account_id when 'ML002' then (dr_amt) else 0 end) as dr_loan_emg,  
    sum(case account_id when 'ML002' then (balance) else 0 end) as bal_loan_emg  
from TEMP_MEMBER_STATEMENT  
group by tran_date, tran_id  
order by tran_date, cast(tran_id as INT);
```

Comment: Error near `LIMIT 0, 30`? Where's `LIMIT 0, 30` in your query?

Comment: as a side note: you don't need the brackets around the column names in the CASE statements. `then balance else ...` is enough.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `int` target for the [CAST function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). it's either `SIGNED` or `UNSIGNED`, eg.

```
ORDER BY ..., CAST(tran_id AS SIGNED)
```